# PyQt4 doesn't work consistently

Tags: python, pyqt, pycharm, pyqt4

I downloaded PyQt4 with apt-get for both python 2 and python 3, (although I will only use it in python3 for the moment). So I wrote something simple with PyCharm.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()

window.show()
```

It gives me a Module Not Found Error for PyQt4. I thought that the problem was with Pycharm, so I installed PyQt4 from Settings>Project Interpreter. It didn't work.

When I wrote it line after line to the python console inside Pycharm, it gave me a module not found error. When I did the same from the terminal (after executing python3) everything works fine. But, when I try to run the file with the code using `python3 test.py` it doesn't open any window, neither gives an error.

My OS is Lubuntu 18.04. 
Thank you.

Comment: Did you install PyQt on Pycharm?

Comment: Yes, from settings.

Comment: Either way, if the problem was with PyCharm, shouldn't it run in terminal?

Comment: add at the end
`sys.exit (app.exec_ ())`
and run `python3 test.py`

Comment: @S.Nick, you're right. So only Pycharm have a problem.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem with Pycharm. I checked again the installation in settings>project interpreter and I don't see the pyqt4 package. I tries to reinstall it, it says that the installation is successful, but it doesn't appear in the installed packages. Any suggestions?